# link wordpress users "wp_users" with another php script

Tags: wordpress

I use wordpress as content manager with user accounts
and using another php script with separate user table 
I manage to link the usernames and passwords from the two tables to be one login data in the wordpress and the other php script
Is that possible to done with the "wp_users" table?

Comment: Yes it is possible, you can load wp environment in you scropt

Answer (score 0):

To use any of WordPress default functionality from any PHP file outside of the WordPress installation directory.

Add this to the beginning of your external (non-WP) PHP file(s):

```
<?php
    require('../wp-install-directory/wp-load.php');
?>
```

Once the `wp-load.php` file is included properly, all native WordPress functions are yours for the using.